# Preventing a user from uploading an executable file or script in a given folder

Tags: asp.net

On my website, users can upload static files (typically pictures) in a given folder.

I just saw this post by Scott Hanselman:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsWhenAllowingUserUploadsDontAllowUploadsToExecuteCode.aspx

He recommends to add this in the web.config file to make sure that nothing can be executed in that folder:

```
<location path="upload">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

This seems to work. As a test I put an .aspx file in the folder in question. If I try to access it I get an "access is denied" error message while I can still access the pictures.

What I don't understand is why the uploader still works? Doesn't it need the Write permission to save the pictures in the folder?

Answer (score 1):

what is not clear?
Here what Hanselman says :

> A FIX FOR ARBITRARY CODE EXECUTION IN USER UPLOAD FOLDERS
>
> What was the fix? Well, certainly not allowing someone to upload a
>   file with a .aspx or .php extension for one, **but also to mark the
>   entire uploads folder as not executable!** Here is the updated
>   web.config:

note the bold text: but also mark the entire uploads folder as not executable....and in effect

```
  <handlers accessPolicy="Read" />
```

it means that cannot execute a page like .php,.aspx and so on.

Comment: "Read" should make the folder only readable but with accessPolicy="Read" it is still possible to save (=to write) files in the folder. That's the question I'm asking: how come it is possible to save files in the folder when its policy has been set to read (only)? Or in other words, what does the "Write" policy do if with the "Read" policy you can write in the folder?

Comment: Hi Antony, i'm sorry but i was out. As per my personal experience there's a lot of permissions in IIS read,write,list,modify,read and execute,full permission(which include all permission) and special permission.So i suppose(but i'm not sure) that you have applied only read permission nothing else.Folder are able to write as per iisusr or roles which are enabled instead in that folder you have not the permission to **execute** any script.And you can find confir here http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd391910(v=ws.10).aspx